# Joining numbers using regex

Tags: r, regex, stringr

#### Problem

I have information on financial years embedded in strings in the form 2019-20 in the variable `table_name` (see example below). I need to remove the century (**20**19) and join it with the year component (20**20**). Success would look like **2020**, in this example.

#### Data

```
df <- structure(list(table_name = c("Resident tax rates for 2016-17", 
"Resident tax rates for 2016-17", "Resident tax rates for 2016-17", 
"Resident tax rates for 2016-17", "Resident tax rates for 2015-16", 
"Resident tax rates for 2015-16"), taxable_income = c("$18,201 – $37,000", 
"$37,001 – $87,000", "$87,001 – $180,000", "$180,001 and over", 
"$18,201 – $37,000", "$37,001 – $80,000"), tax_on_this_income = c("19c for each $1 over $18200", 
"$3572 plus 32.5c for each $1 over $37000", "$19822 plus 37c for each $1 over $87000", 
"$54232 plus 45c for each $1 over $180000", "19c for each $1 over $18200", 
"$3572 plus 32.5c for each $1 over $37000"), cumm_tax_amt = c(0, 
3572, 19822, 54232, 0, 3572), tax_rate = c(19, 32.5, 37, 45, 
19, 32.5), threshold = c(18200, 37000, 87000, 180000, 18200, 
37000)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

#### My attempt

```
str_extract(df$table_name, pattern = "\\b\\d+\\b\\-(?=\\d+\\b)")
```

Comment: What is your actual expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use two capture groups to extract year from `table_name`

```
sub(".*(\\d{2})\\d{2}-(\\d{2})", "\\1\\2", df$table_name)
#[1] "2017" "2017" "2017" "2017" "2016" "2016"
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `substring` and should be faster

```
paste0("20", substring(df$table_name, nchar(df$table_name)-1))
#[1] "2017" "2017" "2017" "2017" "2016" "2016"
```